# The silent tag... dismember and burninate?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[image]

The [silent](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/silent) tag is used in at least two different contexts , to do with [silent-installs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/silent-installs) and [silent-cooling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/silent-cooling) - could we get rid of the silent tag, and replace them with seperate, more accurate tags?

Comment: So, you're not asking for a burnination, but community opinion on a manual retagging?

Comment: pretty much. I think. The tag as is is utterly unclear, and would be better off split. once its retagged though, the tag needs to be burninated.

Comment: Just go ahead and retag these few questions, then we can call in the airstrike.

Answer (score 2):

[silent](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/silent) has been cleared.

Comment: A proper burnination would prevent it from reappearing though.

Comment: @DanielBeck system'll auto delete the tag in few hours

Comment: Yep and tomorrow someone else will add it to a question. We really should blacklist it.

Comment: well the request is for burnination aka tag delete, not blacklist @DanielBeck

Comment: What possible use is deletion if the tag just reappears days later?

Comment: In the long term, given the fact that we still have so many stupid tags, none really. I guess it would make sense to request to blacklist the really stupid ones right away instead of only removing them. So maybe we should clarify this for every new `[retag-request]`, like you just did here. @DanielBeck

Comment: @DanielBeck tag creation requires a bit of rep.

Comment: … but we still find useless tags every week? Somebody with enough rep must have created them.

Comment: @Sathya If that were an effective requirement, we wouldn't have all that crap around, especially not tags that were just deleted. `[apple]` comes to mind.

Comment: @DanielBeck regardless of rep, people do stupid stuff. Also, feel free to raise a blacklist request. Mods can't blacklist and devs have made it clear in the past that blacklists are rarely applied